# Set up a straightforward json api for a git repo

Tags: json, git, api, host

I want to use a basic functionality available through many different git libraries: accessing tree, blob and diff objects. But I want to do so through http, ideally returning the responses as json.

In this way I can expose this behaviour from one of our servers and then have the rest of our team able to build exciting functionality upon our git.

I’m aware that the github api will expose similar functionality, but for various reasons we’re self hosting our repos at the moment.

I’m wondering if there’s any existing app that does this (mapping for example libgit2), and if not what would be the most straightforward way to go about this.